# Javascript animating several DIV's in a sequence

Tags: javascript

I want to animate div sequentially, but can not understand how to go about it, this is my code which want to animate

```
<div id="project_container">
    <div class="project_box">
        <img src="images/project.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="project_box">
        <img src="images/project1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="project_box">
        <img src="images/project2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="project_box">
        <img src="images/project3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="project_box">
        <img src="images/project4.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="project_box">
        <img src="images/project5.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here we have similar type of 6 div, which name . When animation start first div animate and other 5 div hide and when first div animation complete, second div start animate and next 4 div hide, similarly when second div complete animation, third div start these animation continue when last div animation complete.

Comment: Have you tried anything? and with animation/transition what do you mean? there a whole lot you can do with jQuery

Comment: We need to see your JavaScript code.

Comment: I am trying animation first time fadeIn effect, when i animate $('.project_box').fadeIn(); all content fadeIn,but i want to fadeIn first project_box class,then second project_box class similarly continue last div

Comment: i can not get first,second, third, fourth, five and sixth

Comment: you have to call the animation on a single box. `$('.project_box')` will return all boxes. instead use `$(boxes[box_count])` ... see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution of these question, these answer must be written recursive formulla

var total_div = $('.project_box').length;
var count = 0;

```
function do_animate(){
     if(count<total_div){
        $('.project_box').eq(count).animate({'opacity':1,'width':'320px'},{
                duration:1000,
                complete:function(){
                    count++;
                    do_animate();
                }
            });
        }       
}

do_animate();
```

Answer (score 3):

i'd use jQuery to do the animation. check out the working Demo:

<kbd>**[FIDDLE Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KVyJ5)**</kbd>

for quick reference, here is the javascript code:

```
var box_count = -1;
// store boxes in a variable for later reference, this increases javascript speed
var boxes = $('#project_container').children();

// initially hide all boxes
boxes.hide();


var animate_box = function(){
    // get next box
    box_count++;

    //check if boxes are left
    if(box_count < boxes.length ){ 
        //do your Animation
        $(boxes[box_count]).fadeIn({
            //call animation again once complete
            complete: animate_box
        });
    }
}

//start first animation
animate_box();
```

Comment: yeah done my animation, but i try to recursive my code                       function project_animation($i){
  $('.project_box').eq($i).animate({'opacity':1,'width':'320px'},{duration:1500});
 }
 
 
  $('.project_box').eq(0).animate({'opacity':1,'width':'320px'},{
  
  duration:1500,
   complete:function(){
    for($i=1;$i<total_div;$i++){
     project_animation($i);
    }
   }
  });

Comment: please add your javascript example to the question. it's really hard to read in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/2Q9qG/)**</kbd>

Using the RAW JavaScript maybe a bit difficult, but If you prefer to use jQuery, a **recursive** function can do it for you:

```
$(function () {
    function show() {
        // get first hide element and show it 
        $('.project_box:not(.completed):first').show(500, function () {
            // mark it as completed
            $(this).addClass('completed');

            // show next one
            show();
        });
    }

    // invoke the function for the first time
    show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to user Jquery to do that

[This is the API document of Jquery animation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

You can easily achieve like this :

```
  $('.project_box').animate({
    width: '100px'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
```

For your case, to animatie one by one:

```
var childArray = new Array();
$(". project_box").each(function(){
  childArray.push($(this));
});
runAnimation();

int count = 0;
function runAnimation(){
  childArray[0].animation({ width: '100px' }, 1000, function(){
    if(++count < childArray.length)
     runAnimation();
  });
}
```

PS: I didnt try it, But the structure is ok, You try to follow the structure :D

Comment: Im not sure that it is best way to do. it is going to be function(){function(){function(){function(){function(){}}}}}. something like this